# how to get the value of selected option in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can't get the value selected when i press the "enviar" button
this is my code
i made a edit
ths snippet is working but not this code
the console.log is showing always "sugerencias"

html

```
            <ion-content class="has-header has-subheader">
    <button ng-click="im(seleccionado)">sdaodisa</button>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label class="item item-select">
                <span class="input-label">Asunto</span>
                <select ng-model="seleccionado" ng-options="item for item in arrayj"></select>

            </label>
        </div>

    </form>
</ion-content>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('starter');

app.controller('controladorSugerencias', function ($scope) {

    $scope.arrayj = ['sugerencias', 'reclamos'];
    $scope.seleccionado = $scope.arrayj[0];

    $scope.im = function () {
        console.log($scope.seleccionado)
    };

});
```

Comment: this works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/3VHXOAlKScWElgU43o7X?p=preview/.  However, `seleccionado` is a primitive, and is subject to scope inheritance issues, particularly if this code was wrapped inside something else like an `ng-repeat` or `ng-if\show\hide`.  **ALWAYS** use a dot in angular bindings.  see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: Can you add a simple working version of your code in the code snippet? :)